# I am not able to write (put) to Hadoop MiniCluster i created

Tags: java, hadoop, localhost

```
    null: [HTTP/1.1 405 HTTP method 
    PUT is not supported by this 
    URL]
    Server: 
    [Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)]
    Pragma: [no-cache]
    Content-Length: [0]
    X-FRAME-OPTIONS: [SAMEORIGIN]
    Date: [Wed, 13 Oct 2021  
     17:05:16 GMT]
```

'''
private static void putTest() throws IOException {
System.out.println("putTest : Entry");

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:50070/webapps/v1/longdata.txt&op=CREATE");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.getOutputStream().write("Hey Guys".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Map<String, List<String>> headers = con.getHeaderFields();
for (String header : headers.keySet())
        {
            
System.out.println(header + ": " + headers.get(header));
        }
System.out.println("putTest : Exit");
```

}

'''

Answer (score 0):

[You need two requests](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File) - one to the namenode port, which creates the file on the namenode, then that **returns** a datanode address where you send the second address to write the content stream.

However, you are using Java, so just use `hadoop-client` dependency with the `FileSystem.create` method, do not use `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: Thanks alot for the suggestion, i will try hadoop-client.
Meanwhile tried the curl as in the link u sent. Got this error
 
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/yesh/foo/bar?op=MKDIRS'

GOt the error :
Error 500 org/apache/http/message/TokenParser. 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. Will check for dependency for this class and retry.

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4M1C.png

Comment: Never seen that before. If the namenode's classpath is correct, that class should be found... (If you're running Hadoop on windows, you'll most likely get classpath errors like this) Also, I haven't used Hadoop since version 2.7, but the server definitely should not be returning a Java stacktrace in the response. I'd suggest creating a HADOOP JIRA ticket with that information